# Static file server with OWIN -> files not found error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting, azure-service-fabric

My application is running in Azure Service Fabric. In my application I'm using asp.net web api with angularJS as frontend. My web api is self hostet with OWIN/Katana and that works great.

To serve the static files to the client, I'm using OWIN static fileserver. To use the fileserver I took the configuration from Service Fabric examples.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {   
            HttpConfiguration httpConfig = this.ConfigureWebApi();
            FileServerOptions fileServerOptions = this.ConfigureFileSystem(appBuilder);

            appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(this.ConfigureWebApi());
            appBuilder.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);  
        }

private FileServerOptions ConfigureFileSystem(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            PhysicalFileSystem physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\wwwroot");
            FileServerOptions fileOptions = new FileServerOptions();

            fileOptions.EnableDefaultFiles = true;
            fileOptions.RequestPath = PathString.Empty;
            fileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
            fileOptions.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" };
            fileOptions.StaticFileOptions.FileSystem = fileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
            fileOptions.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;

            return fileOptions;
        }
```

The directory of the files looks like this:

```
wwwroot

--+ app

----+ content

------+ css

-------- site.css

----+ bower_components

------+ angular

-------- angular.min.js

----- app.js

--- index.html
```

All these files are also in the bin/Debug/ folder after build. When I'm opening the adress `http://localhost:80/` in browser I'm getting the `index.html` file. But all other files except of `http://localhost:80/app/app.js` can't be found.

The references in index.html look like this:

```
<link href="app/content/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
```

I tried a lot of other configurations, but it didn't work. Is there anything wrong, what I can't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. To copy all files from the `wwwroot` folder to the `Debug/bin/` folder, I use this command in Visual Studio: `XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)WebAppApi.Service\wwwroot" "$(TargetDir)wwwroot" /s /i /y`. I thought it is the same like I would set the "Copy To Output Directory"-property to "Copy if newer" or "copy always". The `XCOPY` command copies all files into the debug folder. But in Azure Service Fabric there is also a "main" debug folder for all included services (`\[application name]\pkg\Debug\[service project name]Pkg\Code\wwwroot`). And in that folder there is no `wwwroot` folder, because all files have "Do not copy" as "Copy To Output Directory"-property except of `index.html` and `app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a few hours with the same problem. Except that I needed to copy
generated files from a webpack build. So I added the follow snippet to the  `sfproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FrontendApplication>FrontendAppName</FrontendApplication>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <ClientSourceFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)$(FrontendApplication)\app\build\**\*.*" />    
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CopyAppToPackage" AfterTargets="CollectServiceCodeFiles">
 <Copy SourceFiles="@(ClientSourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\pkg\$(ConfigurationName)\$(FrontendApplication)Pkg\Code\wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)" />
</Target>
```

`app\build` is the output directory of webpack and `wwwroot` is the directory used by the `PhysicalFileSystem`.

This solves the problem that one of the tasks in the service fabric build target cleans the package directory.